# Bootstrap 4 - Having two carousels in the same page makes the last item to bug out overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to implement two carousels into the same page but for some reason when I do that, on both carousels the last few items bug out overlapping and it resets on the 1st card. Is there a way to work around or am I missing something? It could be a missing ID or something but I did change them up and I cannot pin point the issue.

Any help would be nice. Thanks!

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KasunWijesekara/mdcuy71r/1/)

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="news-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row pt-5 pb-4">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="market-updates">Market Updates</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container" id="market-update-cards">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-header" href="#" role="button">View All</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<!-- Deal Spotlights Area -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row pt-5 pb-4">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="deal-updates">Deal Spotlight</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container" id="deal-update-cards">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="DealCar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarouselTwo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarouselTwo" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-header" href="#" role="button">View All</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Deal Spotlights Area -->
</div>
  <!-- Main Content -->
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;

    if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
      var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
      for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction == "left") {
          $(".carousel-item")
            .eq(i)
            .appendTo(".carousel-inner");
        } else {
          $(".carousel-item")
            .eq(0)
            .appendTo($(this).find(".carousel-inner"));
        }
      }
    }
  });
});


  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#DealCar").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;

    if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
      var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
      for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction == "left") {
          $(".carousel-item")
            .eq(i)
            .appendTo(".carousel-inner");
        } else {
          $(".carousel-item")
            .eq(0)
            .appendTo($(this).find(".carousel-inner"));
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    transition: none;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please re-post it as a Executable Snippet instead of code-blocks so that we can understand your issue completely.

Comment: Hey @AhmarAamir I added a JS Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/KasunWijesekara/mdcuy71r/1/ See whether you get an idea. Thanks!